# Domain without ssl certificate redirecting to different ssl domain

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have two domains set up on a Digital Ocean droplet (with nginx). I've installed a SSL certificate in one of them (domain1) and everything is fine with that one. The second domain (domain2), does not require a SSL certificate but if I try to access https://domain2 is showing me the content of domain1 and giving me a certificate error (This page is not secure).

I understand the certificate error, but I don't want the contents of domain1 being displayed in https://domain2

Is it a configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nginx` always has a *default server*, the one that is used if the `server_name` does not match. If you only have one server block with `listen 443`, then that is the implicit default server for all `https` connections irrespective of server name.

You will need to set up an explicit *catch-all* server for `https` connections, or add `listen 443 ssl` to an existing `server` block to act as the *catch-all* server.

You can reuse the same *certificate file* and you will continue to get certificate errors if anyone attempts to use it, but at least your other domains will not be exposed.

For example:

```
ssl_certificate     /path/to/crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;    

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain1;
    ...
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    return 403;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) and [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#certificate_with_several_names) for more.