# Nginx - Accessing https main domain when accessing http based secondary domain with https

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx.
I have two domains on same server.
One based on `https` & another on `http`

**i.e:**

```
https://main.site.com  //Accessing a node server app on port 3000
```

**And**

```
http://secondary.site.com //Accessing a node server app on port 9000
```

When I try to access `https://secondary.site.com`, it actually accesses my `https://main.site.com` server code, it should redirect from `https://secondary.site.com` to `http://secondary.site.com`

Here is my nginx config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {  

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  main.site.com;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass          http://main.site.com:3000;
                        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
                        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                }
        }


        server {
                listen               443;
                server_name          main.site.com;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass          http://main.site.com:3000;
                        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
                        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                 }
                ssl                  on;
                ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certificates/cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certificates/kry.pkey;
                ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_ciphers  !EDH:!AECDH:!ADH:!DSS:!RC4:ECDSA:HIGH:+3DES;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; #courbe ECDH
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";
        }

        server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  secondary.site.com;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass          http://secondary.site.com:9000;
                        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
                        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                }
        }



        # set client body size #
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

}
```

Comment: You don't have a `server` block for `https://secondary.site.com`, therefore `nginx` will use your one and only `https` site. [This link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) may help.

Comment: I want `https://secondary.site.com` to redirect to `http://secondary.site.com`, so that it can use node server with 9000 port

Comment: Do you have a certificate for `secondary.site.com`? You will need to add a `server` block for `secondary.site.com` which listens on port 443.

Comment: I only have certificates for https://main.site.com, and I only want main.site.com on https, i want secondary.site.com on http

Comment: And secondary.site.com should access node server app on port 9000 even if some one tries to access secondary.site.com with https, it should not use the node server app with port 3000, it should first redirect to secondary.site.com with http so it will automatically use the node server app with port 9000

Comment: You need a *catch-all* server on port 443 to stop other subdomains using your main domain by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481729/domain-without-ssl-certificate-redirecting-to-different-ssl-domain/42482633#42482633). But be advised, you cannot redirect from `https` to `http` without browser warnings **unless** you have a legitimate certificate for that subdomain.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is the why cant I have one domain on https and another on http on same server?

Comment: See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) - there is always a default server - and unless you explicitly define one, `nginx` will use the first server block with a matching `listen` port. To isolate your domains the way you want to, you will need to define a default server for ports 80 and 443 that basically do nothing.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for helping, can I block the request or something if someone tries to access my secondary.site.com with https? because I really dont want my main.site.com be used by this mistake

Comment: Yes. That was the answer I sent you earlier.

Comment: I tried it but its not working, it crashed my nginx , can you configure my nginx please and put it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want your main site on https and secondary on http, you can use something like below

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {  

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        server {
            listen 80 default;
            server_name _;
            return 301 http://secondary.site.com;
        }

        server {
                listen  443 ssl;
                server_name  main.site.com;
                ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/certificates/cert.pem;
                ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/certificates/kry.pkey;
                ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                ssl_ciphers  !EDH:!AECDH:!ADH:!DSS:!RC4:ECDSA:HIGH:+3DES;
                ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
                ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; #courbe ECDH
                add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000";

                location / {
                        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:3000;
                        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
                        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                }
        }

        server {
                listen       80;
                server_name  secondary.site.com;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                        proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
                        proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
                        proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
                        proxy_read_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                }
        }



        # set client body size #
        client_max_body_size 20M;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

}
```

In this `secondary.site.com` only listens on port 80, and main only on port https. I have a default redirect for any http traffic directly to secondary site. But you can customize that based on your requirements